# how to draw text on view?

Tags: android

i am new to android. I want to develop one simple application that can allow user to draw anything on screen like allowing user to draw shapes or signature on screen (View).in J2ME we can use pointerDragged() method but i dont know how to do it in android.i tried with onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) but not able to do. Please help.

---

Thanks a lot. Its working very fine. But one problem is there, Drawing is not that much smooth, i mean when i tried to drag the screen drawing is very bold and i want to restrict the user to draw in limited area. Please suggest me. Awaiting for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Please ask more clearly, "how to draw text" is not what you are asking in the body of your questions.

Comment: Also there are a lot of duplicates of this question.  Did you search before asking? [SO] has a very good search facility

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve is to create a view overriding onDraw(Canvas v),onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) and onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh). Below is code snippet to it. I believe it is self-explanatory.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);

        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

All you have to do is to call `setContentView(new MyView(this));` from your activity class. Hope this will help you.

**Disclaimer: The code snippet isn't mine. I also got it from somewhere from the net. The credit goes to whoever wrote it first.

Comment: I am  sorry,I am new to stackoverflow too.. my clear requirement is to provide user interface where user has to do his signature on screen.sorry for bad explailnation. Please help me.

Comment: In your layout-xml file, add in a Layout (LinearLayout,RelativeLayout,..).

Instead of setContentView(new MyView(this)), just use youLayout.addView(new MyView(this)).

That should do it.